# ALL FILE ACCESS permission for android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am changing target sdk to 30 for my project but little bothering about using ALL FILE ACCESS permission in the code. As per the google, apps who are using this permission without any proper usage will be removed from the play store. But my app needs access to the external sd card storage. We are creating folder in that location and placing all the app related files there. We don't have any application server so we cannot even implement scoped storage because with scoped storage all the data in the apps internal storage will be deleted.Once this data is deleted, it can resync from app server and restore all the data but we cannot do this , our app is offline so we are using this external storage. The customer support team will be there who will manage this storage and push files to this location manually. All our devices configuration will be saved there. So we don't want it to get deleted even the app is removed. So what should I do here? Should I continue implementing ALL FILE ACCESS permission in the android code? Will the app be removed?

Comment: Are the files created by your app meaningful to other application? If not, removing them along with uninstallation is a better practice. Make a proper backup/restore feature in your app to export/import the data if you really need to. That being said, you can still use the [shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared)

Comment: `access to the external sd card storage. We are creating folder in that location` Two times unclear. Do you mean a removable micro sd card? And which location exactly?

Comment: `with scoped storage all the data in the apps internal storage will be deleted` No  you can set a flag in manifest file and doing so the user is asked at uninstall if private data should be kept.

Comment: `The customer support team will be there who will manage this storage and push files to this location manually.` That i do not understand. I thought the app would create its files. How can they be equal to what support has?

Comment: App files generated by our app is not meaningful to other app. But those files contains the configuration files of some hardware and uninstalling the app will delete all this file if we opt for scoped storage, but we cannot afford deleting these files and losing all our configured data.

Comment: Yes, we are creating one folder under shared storage

Comment: There are multiple ways of file stored in our app shared storage folder. Some files are generated from the app itself but some are manually pushed into the created folder.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by shared storage. Please mention full path. And you did not react on `removable micro sd card`. You are supposed to react on all comments. We have to know what you do.

Comment: `App files generated by our app is not meaningful to other app. But those files contains the configuration files of some hardware and uninstalling the app will delete all this file if we opt for scoped storage, but we cannot afford deleting these files and losing all our configured data.` Yes that we know already. That was the problem described in your post. Why are you repeating it? Better react on the things i ask you to explain. Are you telling that support will push files to scoped storage (apps private storage)?

Comment: You better explain how all starts. Is it that for all new devices your app is installed and support pushes files to them? Then what about files create by your app? I asked if they were different ones but you did not react.

Answer (score 0):

As per new guidelines, we don't require permissions for Version 10 and above. Please check scoped storage in android - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Answer (score 0):

There are at least five scenarios to get what you want.

1. Add `android:hasFragileUserData="true"` to application tag in manifest file. At uninstall the user will be asked to preserve data. The user can spoil it, yes.
2. Create a folder in public Documents directory and write your files there using classic file means. After reinstall let the user choose the folder with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. You have full access to the files using further `Storage Access Framework` methods.
3. The same as 2. but now using Storage Access Framework to create folders and files.
4. The same as 2. but now using the MediaStore to create folder and files.
5. Hmmm.. at the moment it wil not come to mind .. ;-)

Comment: How can storage access framework is useful for me here? My requirement is , we have folder created by our app in the shared storage and that folder should be accessible to everyone when we are connecting to laptop/ pc to push files in it.

Comment: I explained how SAF can be used to solve your problem. Pretty sad you come up with a usefull question. I dont understand.

Comment: I am using mediastore api to create folder and files. Now I am successfully able to create folder named SUS  inside Download directory using mediastore . So all the files are saving now in Download/ SUS/  path. But our requirement is, we are copying some files in the same SUS directory from pc. This copied files are not tracking anywhere in the mediastore so I am not able to list down it on my recyclerview. Rest of the files created by the app is displaying in the list. How can I list copied files as well?

Comment: That i told already: let the user choose that SUS directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. After that you can list the files in it using DocumentFile or DocumentsContract.

Comment: yes but if user is selecting some other folder then it will list down other folder files. And everytime user will have to select the directory.  This will be confusing for the users.

Comment: The user only once has to select that directory. Further you can let the picker open in that SUS directory already.

Answer (score -1):

On a Samsung Galaxy Tab S8, with a One Terabyte SD card, note that it takes a little while after boot for the card to get fully mounted.

If one opens the app too quickly, you will get this message.

Fix:  when you boot the tablet, check the SD card in a file manager.  If it is there and shows free space, you will be able to use it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).