# Is it possible to persisit a file after app uninstall with Android 11?

Tags: android, android-11, scoped-storage

I have a small XML data file containing some licensing information that I would like to leave on the device even after the app is uninstalled. Is there a way to do it with Android 11?

It appears due to Scoped Storage, I am limited to storing data to a designated app folder in external or internal storage. And in each case, the data is deleted when the app is deleted.

Is it even possible to persist a file on Android 11?

Comment: You do not get notified when your app is about to be uninstalled so you would have to write this XML file so ignoring Scoped Storage you would have to write this file at some point after installation

Comment: `You do not get notified when your app is about to be uninstalled ` @tyczj Try `android:hasFragileUserData="true" in application tag of manifest file.`

Comment: @blackapps that shows a dialog generated by the System, the app does not get notified itself

Comment: @tyczj, That does not matter as the file already exists. And there are other possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009368/all-file-access-permission-for-android-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file already exists and not trying to create the file at the time of being uninstalled your options are limited and not really good.

There is no way to keep a file around without user interaction. Your only option is really to use the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file) to save the file. What happens here is you have to have the user pick where they want to save the file via file picker intent. Get the uri path in `onActivityResult` and use that to save the file.

Aside from requiring user intervention this also puts your file that has the licensing information in a publicly accessible location where anyone can get it which might not be something you want

That's really your only option if you want to keep a file around after your app has been uninstalled.

Comment: Well there are more. Repeat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009368/all-file-access-permission-for-android-app

Comment: Thank you. However, I manage to see a popular ColorNote app, still able to retain data after uninstallation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqG4n_0xmVI Do you have idea how to achieve so? As, I do not see a screen like https://i.imgur.com/HfJjixE.png , which requires user to explicit pick file/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method.

When app start for the first time, call an API and send deviceId in body.

if deviceId exists =>  device is existing device  => download existing XML file in that particular device.

else device is new device => do whatever you want