# In Android 11, how is it possible, for an app to retain data after uninstallation, without SAF user interaction to pick a file/ folder location?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Based on [Is it possible to persisit a file after app uninstall with Android 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69045388/is-it-possible-to-persisit-a-file-after-app-uninstall-with-android-11/69046215#comment126913389_69046215)

In Android 11, It seems like almost impossible to retain user data locally, after app uninstallation. Unless we are using SAF, which requires explicit user interaction, to select file/ dialog using this system UI

[image]

Or, by using `android:hasFragileUserData="true"` flag, which will pop up the following UI during uninstallation - https://www.xda-developers.com/android-10-manifest-flag-developers-retain-app-data-before-uninstalling/

However, to my suprise, I do notice a popular app in the market, which able to cleanly retain user multiple backup data, with 0 user interaction, and not using `android:hasFragileUserData="true"` flag method.

This is a video, to show how it is able to cleanly read the retained data, after re-installation (I have already did a clean uninstall, before capturing the video) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqG4n_0xmVI

Does anyone has any idea, how I can achieve such "magic"?

Comment: Are you talking about [data backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup)? You can certainly backup and restore the user's data upon reinstall, but that doesn't mean any data is retained on the device after an uninstall.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that isn't using Android's data backup feature. As you can see in the video, if I do not grant storage permission to the app, the app is not able to display the list of previous app data (https://youtu.be/UqG4n_0xmVI?t=30) . Hypothesis is that, reading data stored by Android's data backup feature, shouldn't require storage feature. If permission required, high chance is that, the data is stored at external app's sandbox folder.

Comment: I've installed the colornote right after I saw the youtube video, and I believe that what the apps did was online backup. You have to be signed in to google/facebook before inserting the data, only then the data will be synced once you re-install the apps..